# Unit of measurement of PERF_COUNT_SW_TASK_CLOCK

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, perf

In [`perf_event_open`](http://web.eece.maine.edu/%7Evweaver/projects/perf_events/perf_event_open.html), one of the flags that can be passed in `PERF_COUNT_SW_TASK_CLOCK`, whose description says:

```
     This reports a clock count specific to the task that is running.
```

However, it is not documented what is the unit of this timer.

So, how do I convert the number returned from this to nanoseconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't we conduct a small test to figure it out. I'll be using a timer that I know the unit of, `time.h`'s `time()`, and comparing it to `PERF_COUNT_SW_TASK_CLOCK`. The way they count time is different, and I expect `PERF_COUNT_SW_TASK_CLOCK`'s result to be smaller but in the same order of magnitude.

Here's the code I used:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <linux/hw_breakpoint.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

void main() {
    // Setting up the perf fd
    struct perf_event_attr pe;
    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
    pe.type = PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE;
    pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe.config = PERF_COUNT_SW_TASK_CLOCK;
    pe.disabled = 1;
    pe.exclude_kernel = 1;
    pe.exclude_hv = 1;
    // glibc doesn't expose perf_event_open, so directly calling the syscall
    int fd = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &pe, 0, -1, -1, 0);
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

    // For comparing with a known unit
    time_t time_start = time(0);
    long long count_start;
    read(fd, &count_start, sizeof(long long));

    // Very long calculation
    int a = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<10000; j++)
            a++;

    // Results
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
    long long count_finish;
    read(fd, &count_finish, sizeof(long long));
    time_t time_finish = time(0);

    printf("time(): %d\n", time_finish-time_start);
    printf("PERF_COUNT_SW_TASK_CLOCK: %lld\n", count_finish-count_start);
    return;
}
```

The results are

```
time(): 23
PERF_COUNT_SW_TASK_CLOCK: 22565098436
```

So it appears that it is being counted in nanoseconds already.